# Registering a Generics Implementation of a Generic Interface in StructureMap

Tags: structuremap

i have a generic interface

```
public interface IDomainDataRepository<T>
{
    T[] GetAll();
}
```

with a generic implementation

```
public class DomainDataRepository<T> : IDomainDataRepository<T>
{
    public virtual T[] GetAll()
    {
        return GetSession().Linq<T>().ToArray();
    }
}
```

how do I register it in StructureMap so that if I request `IDomainDataRepository<State>` then it will new up a `DomainDataRepository<State>`. Furthermore if I decide to implement a `CountryDomainDataRepository` and I request a `IDomainDataRepository<Country>` I want to get the specific implementation.

```
public class CountryDomainDataRepository : IDomainDataRepository<State>
{
    public virtual Country[] GetAll()
    {
        return GetSession().Linq<Country>().ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this by configuring the generic open type to use a concrete open type:

```
    [TestFixture]
public class open_generic_registration
{
    [Test]
    public void should_resolve_to_the_configured_concrete_instance_of_T()
    {
        var container = new Container(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.For(typeof (IDomainDataRepository<>)).Use(typeof (DomainDataRepository<>));
        });

        container.GetInstance<IDomainDataRepository<string>>().ShouldBeOfType<DomainDataRepository<string>>();
        container.GetInstance<IDomainDataRepository<int>>().ShouldBeOfType<DomainDataRepository<int>>();
        container.GetInstance<IDomainDataRepository<DateTime>>().ShouldBeOfType<DomainDataRepository<DateTime>>();
    }
}
```